# how to open url with dynamic query string in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications

I have a button on my website which has href https://live.example.net/?dynamic_encypted_query-string, So I wanted to open this url in my webview of ios app. Currently I'm building a web app through capacitor framework where I wrote a code to my WebViewController.swift file

```
    class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://live.example.net/?*")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
}
```

This opens the domain(https://live.example.net) in the web view but i wanted to open it with the query string data.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://live.example.net/?*")
```

I think this doesn't work to fetch the query string data as well.

Comment: Your web server should decrypt the query and navigate to URL you wanted?

Comment: Server has already a functionality to decrypt the query string, all i want to open my whole url in the wkwebview rather than open in a safari browser